# CoreData - Where to include reference to object?

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I'm in the process of moving over the content library of my iOS app from being purely JSON, to leveraging CoreData.

I've produced my datamodels but have one point that I am unclear about, and was hoping to get the ideal approach:

I understand using CoreData to store entries about my individual pieces of content, but want to understand the "right" way to have my produced class have a property or variable that references a functional object that USES the settings in the CoreData entry.

Basic structure:

- `InstrumentEntry.xcdatamodeld`: Contains settings for individual "instrument" entries
- Manual codegen produces `Instrument+CoreDataClass` and `Instrument+CoreDataProperties`
- Instrument.swift: Defines a class which is responsible for producing audio, receiving events, etc.

So,
In my `InstrumentEntry+CoreDataClass.swift`, can I simply add something like `var actualInstrument: Instrument`, or, is this something that I include in the actual Data Model as an Attribute or Property?

**OR**

Do I create my "actualInstrument" and simply have it READ an entry from the CoreData context, rather than maintaining ownership FROM the CD Entry TO an `Instrument` object?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Your `Instrument` object *is* an `NSManagedObject`; it is the Core Data object

Comment: Is your `Instrument.swift` a pre-existing class that you already had for producing audio, receiving events, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use the CD entry "InstrumentEntry" to set up the "Instrument"s values.

Read from the InstrumentEntry CD and pass that along to the init() of my Instrument class, which maintains a reference to the CD.